# pushbullet API takes 30 minutes to deliver note

Tags: python-2.7, pushbullet

Working with Python 2.7 on Raspberry pi, I created a Pushbullet account and installed it on my iPhone 7 (iOS 12.4). In this instance, I'm using a github library from https://github.com/rbrcsk/pushbullet.py  but I've noticed this lag using other methods as well.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pushbullet import Pushbullet

PB_API_KEY = 'o.00000000000000000000000000000000'

print("creating pb object with key:")

try:
   pb = Pushbullet(PB_API_KEY)
except Exception as e:
   print (str(e))
   exit()

print("pushing note:")

try:
   push = pb.push_note('important subject','this is a test')
except Exception as e:
   print (str(e))
   exit()

print ("done")
```

What happens is, when I run this script, it prints "creating pb object with key:" and then it appears to hang.  30 minutes (or so) later the notification appeared on my phone, and I saw that the next two print lines had appeared and the script had completed.

I'm anxious to begin using Pushbullet to push alarm notifications from my PI-GPIO home alarms. It appears to work, but why the big lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to an incorrect ipV6 setting in my router (as in, it was enabled for some reason). This was giving me a stack of gateway and DNS addresses that had to time out before I could get a request out. So - this problem is NOT related to pushbullet.

Sorry about this false alarm.